# typescript, making a c# like delegate, fat arrows, and this

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in an Angular/Typescript project.  I have the following construct i'm building as a light weight pubsub.  This is the subscription in a fluent syntax.

```
   SubscribeEvent.Create(PubSubTopic.testEvent, 
        this.objectId)
       .HandleEventWithThisMethod( (PubSubEventArgs) => 
            {self.handlePEvent(PubSubEventArgs); } )
        .ApplyFilterPredicate((res: PubSubEventArgs) => {
           return (res.sourceObjectId === self.objectId);
       });
```

The part i'd like to simplify is the HandleEventWithThis method. In C#, it'd be `HandleEventWithThisMethod(handlePEvent)`

When I do away with the fat-arrow stuff, I lose track of THIS in the handlePEvent.

Can someone tell me how to simplify the syntax of the `.HandleEventWithThisMethod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some extra brackets and such that you don't need. You can simplify like this:

```
SubscribeEvent
    .Create(PubSubTopic.testEvent, this.objectId)
    .HandleEventWithThisMethod(args => self.handlePEvent(args))
    .ApplyFilterPredicate(res => res.sourceObjectId === self.objectId);
```

or

```
SubscribeEvent
    .Create(PubSubTopic.testEvent, this.objectId)
    .HandleEventWithThisMethod(self.handlePEvent.bind(self))
    .ApplyFilterPredicate(res => res.sourceObjectId === self.objectId);
```

You can't pass `self.handlePEvent` directly is that a function is not inherently tied to the object. If you pass the function reference around and then call the function, by default `this` will not be the object but will be the `Window`.

You can force the function to be bound to the object with a call to `bind` as in `self.handlePEvent.bind(self)`.